# proper implementation of Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

Broadly I'm having issues integrating a Google Apps Script app with my Cloud SQL instance. Specifically, my console caught an error with `Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection` because `Jbdc` wasn't initialized. Please advise.

Code below

```
var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection('jdbc:google:mysql:code-198618:us-central1:instid');
Console.log(conn.getMetaData())

Uncaught ReferenceError: Jdbc is not defined
    at userCodeAppPanel:2
```

Comment: Jdbc is a server side class. You must use it server side only.

Comment: So I can't use it in the JavaScript? Thanks for your answer by the way.

Comment: This is a web app right?. Read client server communication. Use `google.script.run` to  instruct the server to start jdbc.

Comment: Solved, thanks a lot!

Comment: If you think your solution will help others, kindly explain the solution in the answer box below.